# Getting awk syntax error while running belwo script

Tags: shell

Below is the code, where I am getting awk syntax error while running the script.

```
#list of servere where app runs

echo "Servers to be checked :"
cat serverlist
sleep 3
for peer in `cat serverlist`; do
    sleep 3
    echo "Verifying the application environment on node $peer"
    status=$(ssh $peer echo ok 2>/dev/null)
    if [ "$status" == "ok" ];then
        # Check hostname
                ssh -Xt hotcadm@$peer bash -c "
                # Check RAM and SWAP Usages
                free -h | grep -v + > /tmp/ramcache
                printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' -
                echo -e "Ram Usages :"
                cat /tmp/ramcache | grep -v "Swap"
                printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' -
                echo -e "Swap Usages :"
                cat /tmp/ramcache | grep -v "Mem"

                # Check Disk Usages
                df -h| grep  'Filesystem\|/apps*' > /tmp/diskusage
                printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' -
                echo -e "Disk Usages :"
                cat /tmp/diskusage

                # Check System Uptime
                uptime | awk '{print $3,$4}' | cut -f1 -d, > sysuptime
                printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' -
                echo -e "System Uptime Days :"  `cat sysuptime`
                printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' = "
    fi
done
```

After running the code, I am getting the below error. Not sure where I am going wrong. have looked in the internet but I was not able to figure out a solution for the error I am getting.

Error:

```
Verifying the application environment on node hotvlc218
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                     |
|  Use of this network is restricted to authorized users only. User   |
|  activity may be monitored and/or recorded. Anyone using this       |
|  network expressly consents to such monitoring and/or recording.    |
|                                                                     |
|  BE ADVISED: if possible criminal activity is detected, these       |
|  records, along with certain personal information, may be provided  |
|  to law enforcement officials.                                      |
|                                                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
bash: -c: option requires an argument
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ram Usages :
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           31G        31G       300M       736K       747M        11G
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Swap Usages :
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Swap:         2.0G         0B       2.0G
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Disk Usages :
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
                       59G   49G  7.7G  87% /apps
awk: {print ,}
awk:        ^ syntax error
awk: {print ,}
awk:         ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,}
awk: cmd. line:1:          ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Comment: That `bash: -c: option requires an argument` is probably your real error.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to try passing anything that requires complex quoting (such as a multi-line shell script) as an option to ssh. You have embedded quotes (") in your script that will interact poorly with the quotes you've used to surround the entire script, and even if you fixed that it is likely that you would still have problems.

Your life will be much simpler if you pass that to the remote shell on stdin, like this:

```
for peer in `cat serverlist`; do
    sleep 3
    echo "Verifying the application environment on node $peer"
    status=$(ssh $peer echo ok 2>/dev/null)
    if [ "$status" == "ok" ];then
        ssh -Xt hotcadm@$peer bash <<- 'EOF'
        export TERM=xterm
        # Check RAM and SWAP Usages
        free -h | grep -v + > /tmp/ramcache
        printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' -
        echo -e "Ram Usages :"
        cat /tmp/ramcache | grep -v "Swap"
        printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' -
        echo -e "Swap Usages :"
        cat /tmp/ramcache | grep -v "Mem"

        # Check Disk Usages
        df -h| grep  'Filesystem\|/apps*' > /tmp/diskusage
        printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' -
        echo -e "Disk Usages :"
        cat /tmp/diskusage

        # Check System Uptime
        uptime | awk '{print $3,$4}' | cut -f1 -d, > sysuptime
        printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' -
        echo -e "System Uptime Days :"  `cat sysuptime`
        printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' =
        EOF
    fi
done
```

We're using `'EOF'` here because that format inhibits the local shell from performing variable expansion on your script. Also, note that as written it is critical that you are using tabs for indenting, rather than spaces.

Answer (score 0):

your script appears to have multiple issues with unbalanced quotes. At least that's what the shellcheck utility tells me when I run it on your script. This would also be consistent with your error messages from awk, and with the fact that the error occurs inside an awk 'print' statement.

To explore which quotes to fix in order to make the error go away, I suggest that you do the following:

- Install shellcheck on your computer or go to the online version at [www.shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) .
- Weite`#!/usr/bin/bash` in the first line (or whatever your shell happens to be).
- Paste your script below. Then run the check.
- Fix Shellcheck's warning messages one by one. After each fix, test your script on your computer; see if it behaves as you want it to.

This is the best I can do without being able to *run* your script on my computer. I hope it helps anyway.